# PHP y MySql Login, descifrar

Tags: php, html, mysql, formularios

Tengo esto en la **base de datos**:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al hacer el login en el formulario, no me lo hace bien. Se que puede ser la contraseña, porque en la base de datos esta cifrada, una de las soluciones es cifrar la contraseña que meto en el login de la pagina web, para despues compararla con la de la base de datos, **¿pero que tipo de cifrado es el que hace en la base de datos?** Acepto otro tipo de soluciones

Este es mi archivo **inicio_sesion.php**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login y Registro</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="imagen">
    <main>
        <div class="contenedor_todo">
            <div class="caja_informacion">
                <h4>Nos alegramos de verte</h4>
                <h1>BIENVENIDO</h1>
                <h5>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo quia nemo rem dolor eos illo. Modi quos adipisci aperiam temporibus nulla maxime error itaque eveniet iusto, voluptatem inventore explicabo repellat?</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="caja_registro_inicio">  
                <form action="" id="formulario_ini" method="POST">
                    <h2>Iniciar Sesion</h2>
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Correo Electronico" class="silvia3">
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña" class="silvia4">
                    <input type="submit" value="Inicar Sesion" id="inicio" name="enviar">
                    <h4>¿No tienes una cuenta?</h4><a href="registro_usuario.php">Registrarse</a>
                </form>
                <?php
                include ("conexion.php");
                $acentos = $conexion->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

                    if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){
                        
                        $name = $_POST['name'];
                        $password = $_POST['password'];
                        
                        //$filas = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

                            if(strlen($name)==0 || strlen($password)==0){
                                echo"El usuario y la contraseña son obligatorios";
                            }else{
                                $query = "SELECT * FROM `users_table` WHERE `name`='".$name."' && `password`='".$password."'";
                                if(!$consulta = $conexion->query($query)){
                                    echo "ERROR: no se pudo ejecutar la consulta!";
                                }else{
                                    $filas = mysqli_num_rows($consulta);
                                    if($filas == 0){
                                        echo"<script>alert('Error: no se encuentra ninguna contraseña o usuario');</script>";
                                    }else{
                                        echo"<script>alert('Correcto');</script>"; 
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Este es el codigo de registrar usuario, lleva un **password_hash** y dentro la que es por defecto:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] =='POST'){

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    require_once 'connect.php';

    $sql = "INSERT INTO users_table (name, email, password) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$password')";

    if ( mysqli_query($conn, $sql) ) {
        $result["success"] = "1";
        $result["message"] = "success";

        echo json_encode($result);
        mysqli_close($conn);

    } else {

        $result["success"] = "0";
        $result["message"] = "error";

        echo json_encode($result);
        mysqli_close($conn);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: No podemos saber -con exactitud- el cifrado sin ver el código de inserción/actualización. Parece *blowfish*, pero el valor de la sal...?

Comment: En el if ($filas == 0) se supone que debe mostrar el mensaje de error no amigo? Y si la variable $filas es diferente a 0 entonces mostrar el mensaje "correcto"

Comment: En el momento en que se inserta el usuario, se debió hacer un [password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), entonces, cuando vayas a hacer el login, puedes hacer [password_verify](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). Mientras no facilites ese código, pues poco o nada podemos hacer.

Comment: Ya esta editado

Answer (score 1):

Usa la función `password_verify()`, ya que estás usando la función `password_hash()`, no hay forma de descifrar la contraseña, pero sí puedes comparar el texto que envías desde el login con el hash que tienes en DB, aquí un ejemplo:

```
<?php
    $hash = '$2y$07$BCryptRequires22Chrcte/VlQH0piJtjXl.0t1XkA8pw9dMXTpOq';

    if (password_verify('ejemplo123', $hash))
    {
        echo '¡La contraseña es válida!';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'La contraseña no es válida.';
    }
?>
```

Fuente: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-verify.php